# Setting NoteFilter in Evernote API

Tags: python, api, evernote

I have set up my Python page like so (extract):

```
import evernote.edam.userstore.constants as UserStoreConstants
import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient

client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=False)
note_store = client.get_note_store()
```

The problem comes with this code:

```
filter = note_store.NoteFilter
filter.setOrder(NoteSortOrder.UPDATED.getValue())
```

I would then go onto use note_store.findNotesMetadata. However, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setOrder'
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to adapt from the example given [here](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/searching_notes.php)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a working example:

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
from evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes import NoteFilter, NotesMetadataResultSpec
from evernote.edam.type.ttypes import NoteSortOrder

auth_token = 'your-token'
client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token)
note_store = client.get_note_store()

updated_filter = NoteFilter(order=NoteSortOrder.UPDATED)
offset = 0
max_notes = 10
result_spec = NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True)
result_list = note_store.findNotesMetadata(auth_token, updated_filter, offset, max_notes, result_spec)

# note is an instance of NoteMetadata
# result_list is an instance of NotesMetadataList
for note in result_list.notes:
    print note.title
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I am now getting the error that "Store" object has no attribute "NoteFilter". The Evernote API reference (http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/javadoc/com/evernote/edam/notestore/NoteFilter.html) states that NoteFilter is part of notestore, and as per the code in the original post, I have `note_store = client.get_note_store()` Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out it was more complex than I thought. Evernote generates it's clients from Thrift. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is my **FULL** working code:

```py
import os
import sys
import hashlib
import binascii
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import logging

# sys.path.append("lib")
# sys.path.append("libs/evernote-sdk-python3")
sys.path.append("libs/evernote-sdk-python3/lib")

from evernote import *
from evernote.api import *
from evernote.api.client import *
from evernote.edam.limits import *
from evernote.edam.type import *
from evernote.edam.type.ttypes import *
from evernote.edam.notestore import *
from evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes import *
from evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore import *
from evernote.edam.userstore import *
from evernote.edam.userstore.constants import *


ToProcessNotebook = "toProcess"

isSandbox=True
# isChina=False
isChina=True


AuthTokenDict = {
    "sandbox": {
        # China, https://sandbox.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action
        "yinxiang": "change_to_your_token",
        # International
        "evernote": "",
    },
    "production": {
        "yinxiang": "",
        "evernote": "",
    },
}

ServiceHost = ""
AuthToken = ""

if isChina:
    if isSandbox:
        AuthToken = AuthTokenDict["sandbox"]["yinxiang"]
        ServiceHost = "sandbox.yinxiang.com"
    else:
        AuthToken = AuthTokenDict["production"]["yinxiang"]
        ServiceHost = "app.yinxiang.com"
else:
    if isSandbox:
        AuthToken = AuthTokenDict["sandbox"]["evernote"]
        ServiceHost = "sandbox.evernote.com"
    else:
        AuthToken = AuthTokenDict["production"]["evernote"]
        ServiceHost = "app.evernote.com"


gClient = None
gUserStore = None
gNoteStore = None

def init():
    global gClient, gUserStore, gNoteStore
    logFilename = "EvernoteToWordpress_%s.log" % (getCurDatetimeStr())
    loggingInit(logFilename)

    gClient = EvernoteClient(
        token=AuthToken,
        # sandbox=sandbox,
        # china=china,
        service_host=ServiceHost
    )
    logging.info("gClient=%s", gClient)

    gUserStore = gClient.get_user_store()
    logging.info("gUserStore=%s", gUserStore)

    isVersionOk = gUserStore.checkVersion(
        "Evernote EDAMTest (Python)",
        EDAM_VERSION_MAJOR, # UserStoreConstants.EDAM_VERSION_MAJOR,
        EDAM_VERSION_MINOR, # UserStoreConstants.EDAM_VERSION_MINOR
    )
    logging.info("Is my Evernote API version up to date? %s", isVersionOk)

    gNoteStore = gClient.get_note_store()
    logging.info("gNoteStore=%s", gNoteStore)

def EvernoteToWordpress():
    """Process evernote note into wordpress"""
    global gClient, gUserStore, gNoteStore
    notebookList = gNoteStore.listNotebooks()
    notebookListLen = len(notebookList)
    logging.info("Found %s notebooks:", notebookListLen)
    for curNotebook in notebookList:
        logging.info("\tguid=%s,name=%s", curNotebook.guid, curNotebook.name)
        if curNotebook.name == ToProcessNotebook:
            processNotes(curNotebook)
            break

def processNotes(curNotebook):
    """Process each note"""
    logging.info("curNotebook=%s", curNotebook)
    # find all notes in notebook
    searchOffset = 0
    searchPageSize = 100
    searchFilter = NoteStore.NoteFilter()
    searchFilter.order = NoteSortOrder.UPDATED
    searchFilter.ascending = False
    searchFilter.notebookGuid = curNotebook.guid
    logging.info("searchFilter=%s", searchFilter)
    resultSpec = NotesMetadataResultSpec()
    resultSpec.includeTitle = True
    resultSpec.includeContentLength = True
    resultSpec.includeCreated = True
    resultSpec.includeUpdated = True
    resultSpec.includeDeleted = True
    resultSpec.includeNotebookGuid = True
    resultSpec.includeTagGuids = True
    resultSpec.includeAttributes = True
    resultSpec.includeLargestResourceMime = True
    resultSpec.includeLargestResourceSize = True
    logging.info("resultSpec=%s", resultSpec)

    # foundNoteResult = gNoteStore.findNotesMetadata(
    #     authenticationToken=AuthToken,
    #     filter=searchFilter,
    #     offset=searchOffset,
    #     maxNotes=pageSize,
    #     resultSpec=resultSpec
    # )
    foundNoteResult = gNoteStore.findNotesMetadata(AuthToken, searchFilter, searchOffset, searchPageSize, resultSpec)
    logging.info("foundNoteResult=%s", foundNoteResult)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    EvernoteToWordpress()
```

Note: evernote sdk is download from [Evernote SDK for Python 3](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python3)

Latest code: [crifanEvernote.py](https://github.com/crifan/crifanLibPython/blob/master/python3/crifanLib/thirdParty/crifanEvernote.py)