# findNotesMetadata AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, macos, evernote

Found similar questions to this, but the solutions proposed didn't seem to work for me.

I'm struggling to make the findNotesMetadata call.  My getUser() from the userStore works, and my createNote from the notestore works as well.  It is only the call to findNotesMetaData that is failing currently.

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types

dev_token = "blah blah blah"
client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token, sandbox=True)
userStore = client.get_user_store()
user = userStore.getUser()
print user.username

notestore = client.get_note_store()
notebooks = notestore.listNotebooks()

note = Types.Note()
note.title = "I'm a test note!"
note.content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">'
note.content += '<en-note><en-todo/>Hello, world!</en-note>'
note = noteStore.createNote(note)

tags = notestore.listTags()
CheckedTags = set()
for tag in tags:
    if tag.name[0:4] == "CheckThisTag":
        print tag
        CheckedTags.add(tag.guid)

print CheckedTags

myfilter = notestore.NoteFilter()
spec = notestore.NotesMetadataResultSpec()
spec.includeTitle = True
notes = notestore.findNotesMetadata(dev_token, myfilter, 0, 100, spec)
print notes
```

Running this code gets me the following error on the findNotesMetaData line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    notes = notestore.findNotesMetadata(dev_token, filter, 0, 100, spec)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/evernote/api/client.py", line 145, in delegate_method
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/evernote/edam/notestore/NoteStore.py", line 3981, in findNotesMetadata
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/evernote/edam/notestore/NoteStore.py", line 3992, in send_findNotesMetadata
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/evernote/edam/notestore/NoteStore.py", line 12996, in write
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: Let me preface this by saying I have never used this library. What do you expect `notestore.NoteFilter` to be? From reading the source, `notestore.NoteFilter` would be resolved by a custom `__getattr__` method on the `Store` class ([link](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/blob/dd91c1413eca42c033771e3289ecd43008a7de57/lib/evernote/api/client.py#L137)) which returns a method. Basically, I think the problem is that `filter` is a method but `findNotesMetadata` expects it to be an object with a `write` method.

Comment: Hmm.. I would expect myfilter (since filter might have been a keyword, I changed it to myfilter, with the same results btw) to be instance of a NoteFilter, a struct, as described [here](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteFilter) and [here](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/search.php)

Comment: Thanks @FamousJameous, your comment led me down the write path.  Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532862/setting-notefilter-in-evernote-api), I realized I needed to import the types directly, and not just set variables to be "instances" of them by calling Notestore.NoteFilter().. for example.